# Can I put both Epsom Salts and Lectric soda into a bath

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I would like to get the benefits of absorbing Magnesium by using either Epsom salts (magnesium sulphate) or magnesium chloride and the benefit that lectric soda (sodium carbonate) has on sore, tired muscles. Can either or both forms of magnesium and lectric soda be put in a bath together and remain in their original forms to act as they do individually or will they react and form something that won’t do anything or worse do something undesirable?

Answer (score 2):

Mixing solutions of magnesium sulphate or chloride and sodium carbonate is effective way to produce precipitate of magnesium carbonate, known also as the mineral [magnesite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesite).

When filtered out, you would have solution of sodium sulphate (Glauber salt) or sodium chloride (table salt), with eventual excess of one of the used salts.

I doubt it is what you want.

Comment: Addition: $\ce{MgCO3}$ has a low solubility in water (property box on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_carbonate) reports  $\pu{0.0139 g}/\pu{100 mL}$ (at $\pu{25 ^\circ{}C}$); most of it will be *not* in solution, and in consequence, not accessible for anything (maybe "precipitate" is foreign to the OP). Even if, the substance had to travel across layers of skin (much of collagen) prior to reach the muscle. More likely: the warmth of the bath soothes some of the sensation of sore (overstretched / ruptured) muscle fibers if warming up (e.g., prior to a run) was skipped.

Comment: @Buttonwood I see. I wrote it maybe under false impression "precipitate" is a common word, not limited to chemistry or science.

Comment: I agree (depending on language) "precipitate" is not constrained to chemistry, or science.  In comparison of an English general purpose dictionary and Robert, a French one, however, only the later explicitly includes the note of low solubility (though uncertain if by chance by the editors' choice, or by use [of related words] equally in other circumstances, than chemistry), [photo taken](https://imgur.com/a/iUCNa7b).

Comment: @Buttonwood I cannot even without looking remember other suitable verb for solids excluding themselves from solutions. // It reminds me a user objecting against adjective "laconic",  suggesting an alternative I have not known it's meaning, not even ever seeing such a word. (and forgetting it immediately :-)